# SQL, add column which is a foreign key via ALTER TABLE in 1 Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, alter

i want to extend a already created table by a column, but the column is a foreign key. This has to happen in 1 SQL statement.
I know than i can use the ALTER TABLE operation to achieve it, but there is a small error message.

Existing Table:

```
//relation, because table already exists
Relation(A, B, C, D, E, F)
```

//creating a table F

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable`(
`PK` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`H` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`I` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`PK`),
FOREIGN KEY(`I`) REFERENCES `IT`(`I`)
);
```

Attempt to add the column I which is a foreign key(everything in one statement):

```
ALTER TABLE `R`
ADD COLUMN `PK` INT(11) NOT NULL,
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`PK`) REFERENCES `MyTable`(`PK`);
```

Error Message:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.
```

Important: I know there could be a problem if the IT table has entries, but in our case, the table is empty.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
SOLUTION: Removed the constrain "NOT NULL".
Thanks @Milan Švec

```
-------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `MyTable`(
`PK` INT(11),
`H` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`I` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`PK`),
FOREIGN KEY(`I`) REFERENCES `IT`(`I`)
);


ALTER TABLE `R`
ADD COLUMN `PK` INT(11),
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`PK`) REFERENCES `MyTable`(`PK`);

--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try to make the column nullable first. Change it to not nullable later, after filling by real values.

Comment: Sometimes its to easy. Making it nullable first resolved the problem.